# Showing that a function is strictly increasing

Tags: functions

Let $f(x)=x/(1+|x|)$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$ This is a simple question but I am a bit stuck to show directly that $f$ is strictly increasing, so without any tools like the 1st derivative test, so just using inequalities, So any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

for $x > 0,$ the function equals 
$$
\frac{1}{1+1/x}
$$
$x$ is increasing so $1/x$ is decreasing so $1+1/x$ is decreasing so 
$$
\frac{1}{1+1/x}
$$
is increasing.

For $x<0,$ a similar argument. Joining the two cases together is easy.

Comment: You should add on which interval it is decreasing (monotonic, *per se*, is meaningless).

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac x{1+x}=1-\dfrac1{1+x}\;,\;\;\;\;\;1\neq x\ge 0\\{}\\\dfrac x{1-x}=\dfrac1{1-x}-1\;,\;\;-1\neq x<0\end{cases}$$

Thus, the function's domain is

$$\Bbb R\setminus\{-1,\,1\}=(-\infty, -1)\cup(-1,1)\cup(1,\infty)$$

Now,

$$\begin{align}&-1\neq x<0\implies f'(x)=\frac1{(1-x)^2}>0\implies f\;\;\text{is increasing here}\\{}\\&1\neq x\ge 0\implies f'(x)=\frac1{(1+x)^2}>0\implies f\;\;\text{is increasing here}\end{align}$$